# Prometheus Alert Query: If the pod is short lived (e.g., less than 2 minutes) exclude it

Tags: prometheus, promql, prometheus-alertmanager

We have a promql query that alerts us whenever a pod is down, the query gets very noisy for short lived pods. Keeps alerting and auto-resolving. Since a few pods are very short lived and its unlikely for them to reach ready state. I was wondering if we could have a condition in promql itself such that if the pod is short lived (e.g., less than 2 minutes) exclude it from result.

Thank you.

Comment: What is your monitoring setup ? What is your promql query ? I suspect you are using kube_state_metrics  but , if so, we cannot guess how you are using it. Please improve your question such that we can give a relevant answer.  You can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidelines.